# Java - matcher re-reading words

Tags: java, delphi, matcher

I'm trying to create a lexical analyzer for Delphi using java. Here's the sample code:

```
String[] keywords={"array","as","asm","begin","case","class","const","constructor","destructor","dispinterface","div","do","downto","else","end","except","exports","file","finalization","finally","for","function","goto","if","implementation","inherited","initialization","inline","interface","is","label","library","mod","nil","object","of","out","packed","procedure","program","property","raise","record","repeat","resourcestring","set","shl","shr","string","then","threadvar","to","try","type","unit","until","uses","var","while","with"};
String[] relation={"=","<>","<",">","<=",">="};
String[] logical={"and","not","or","xor"};
Matcher matcher = null;
for(int i=0;i<keywords.length;i++){
   matcher=Pattern.compile(keywords[i]).matcher(line); 
   if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Keyword"+"\t\t"+matcher.group());
   }
}
for(int i1=0;i1<logical.length;i1++){
   matcher=Pattern.compile(logical[i1]).matcher(line); 
   if(matcher.find()){
     System.out.println("logic_op"+"\t\t"+matcher.group());
   }
}    
for(int i2=0;i2<relation.length;i2++){
   matcher=Pattern.compile(relation[i2]).matcher(line); 
   if(matcher.find()){
     System.out.println("relational_op"+"\t\t"+matcher.group());
   }
}
```

So, when I run the program, it works but it's re-reading certain words which the program considers as 2 token for example: **record** is a keyword, but re-reads it to find the word **or** for the token logical operators which is from **rec"*or*"d**. How can I cancel out the re-reading of words? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [answer by EvanM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658335/5221149), you need to add a `\b` word boundary matcher before and after the keyword, to prevent substring matching within a word.

For better performance, you should also use the `|` logical regex operator to match one of many values, instead of creating multiple matchers, so you only have to scan the `line` once, and only have to compile one regex.

You can even combine the 3 different kinds of token you are looking for in a single regex, and use capture groups to differentiate them, so you only have to scan the `line` once in total.

Like this:

```
String regex = "\\b(array|as|asm|begin|case|class|const|constructor|destructor|dispinterface|div|do|downto|else|end|except|exports|file|finalization|finally|for|function|goto|if|implementation|inherited|initialization|inline|interface|is|label|library|mod|nil|object|of|out|packed|procedure|program|property|raise|record|repeat|resourcestring|set|shl|shr|string|then|threadvar|to|try|type|unit|until|uses|var|while|with)\\b" +
              "|(=|<[>=]?|>=?)" +
              "|\\b(and|not|or|xor)\\b";
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line); m.find(); ) {
    if (m.start(1) != -1) {
        System.out.println("Keyword\t\t" + m.group(1));
    } else if (m.start(2) != -1) {
        System.out.println("logic_op\t\t" + m.group(2));
    } else {
        System.out.println("relational_op\t\t" + m.group(3));
    }
}
```

You can even optimize it further by combining keywords with common prefixes, e.g. `as|asm` could become `asm?`, i.e. `as` optionally followed by `m`. Will make the keyword list less readable, but would perform better.

In the code above, I did that for the logic ops, to show how, and also to fix the matching error in the original code, where `>=` in the `line` would show up 3 times as `=`, `>`, `>=` in that order, a problem similar to the sub-keyword problem asked for in the question.

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that it reads certain combined symbols like the one you stated wherein `>=` will split up into 3 logic_ops. This helped me too. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add `\b` to your regular expressions for breaks between words. So:

```
Pattern.compile("\\b" + keywords[i] + "\\b")
```

will ensure that the characters on either side of your word aren't letters.

This way "record" will only match with "record," not with "or."

Comment: Although a keyword is unlikely to contain special regex characters, you should still escape it: `Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(keywords[i]) + "\\b")`